# Location stop updating after reset location services to enable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location

My app has a problem updating location after resetting location service to enable. So when the system location service is enabled, my app has no problem updating the location. But if I closed the app and disabled the system location service, then restart the app, it will show an alert to enable the system location service. After enabling location service, then going back to the app, its location has no updating at all. I have the longitude, latitude, heading..etc UIs to indicate whether the location is updated or not. Here are my view's code and location manager class, could someone help me out? Thanks

> View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State var trackingInfo = ARViewContainer.TrackingInfo()
    @State var isLocationServiceOff = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ARViewContainer(trackingInfo: $trackingInfo)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear{
                    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                        locationManager.checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()
                    } else {
                        isLocationServiceOff = true
                    }
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $isLocationServiceOff) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Location Service Disabled"),
                          message: Text("Geospatial experience requires location service enabled"),
                          primaryButton: .default(Text("Setting")){
                            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                                if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION") {
                                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                                }
                            } else {
                                if let url = URL(string: "prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICE") {
                                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                                }
                        }
                    }, secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel")))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> LocationManager class

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    //User could turn location service off, so it's an optional.
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
    func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager!.delegate = self
        }
    }
    
    private func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        guard let locationManager = locationManager else {
            return
        }
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
            
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Restricted location services due to parental controls")
        case .denied:
            print("You have denied this app location permission. Go into settings to change it")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You should not do that via "prefs" it is prohibited by Apple, everything must be done via CLLocationManager itself. Btw, `CLLocationManager` is always available independently of service is off or on.

Comment: Hi Asperi, could you please explain more on my code? Thanks